# How to find text on a page using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I am trying to find the best way to find a word on a page using Nokogiri.

I have a page which has the following text.

```
<p>Modelo: ABC123-A</p>
```

I would like to find the **"Modelo:"** text, and then get the model number after it.

I have had a look around but can't seem to find. So, I thought I would post on here and see if anyone with experience of Nokogiri could shed some light on this for me.

Comment: Why don't you use `watir` to do this job?

Comment: Nice but isn't that just a testing thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `p:contains` selector and get the matching `p` nodes.

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML('<html><body><p>Modelo: ABC123-A</p><br/><p>Nothing here</p><p>Modelo: 4321</p></body></html>')
doc.css('p:contains("Modelo")').map { |x| x.text.split(': ').last }
#=> ["ABC123-A", "4321"]
```

Comment: Cheers Kiddorails, I'll try this out :)

Answer (score 1):

A simple example:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML('<html><body><p>Modelo: ABC123-A</p></body></html>')
doc.css('p').first.content  # => Modelo: ABC123-A
str.split( ': ' )[-1]  # => ABC123-A
```

You could also try [Oga](https://gitlab.com/yorickpeterse/oga), it's lighter than Nokogiri.

Comment: Thanks Mat, I'll have a look at Oga. Looks interesting.